# RISCV64 `li` pseudo instruction and inline asm operand constraints

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, riscv

I work on bare-metal with C99.

---

Please consider...

```
#define FOO 0x234567894567ULL
extern void someFunction(void);

void example(void) __attribute__((naked));
void
example(void)
{
  __asm__ volatile(
    "   li  t0, %[value]   \t\n"
    "   ecall              \t\n"
    : /* no output args */
    : [value]  "i"  ((uint64_t) FOO)
    : "t0"
  );
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sq6TvzzPK)

Using Godbolt's gcc trunk (AND using both gcc-8.2 and gcc-8.5.0), this "compiles" (in all three versions) exactly how I expect, to this output (with pseudo-instructions):

```
   li  t0, 38780996765031       
   ecall
```

However, my actual toolchain uses `SiFive GCC 8.3.0-2019.08.0`. With that, for the code above, the compiler reports:

```
error: asm operand 1 probably doesn't match constraints [-Werror]
```

---

If I change the input operand type from `"i"` to `"r"`, then all three of Godbolt's toolchains continue to work. The only change (which is expected) is that it loads my constant to an intermediate register, and thence into "t0".

```
       lui     a5,%hi(.LC0)
       ld      a5,%lo(.LC0)(a5)
       li      t0, a5           
       ecall
  .LC0:
        .dword  38780996765031
```

However, my SiFive toolchain COMPILER generates the same assembly, but the ASSEMBLER chokes as it reports:

```
Error: illegal operands `li t0,a5'
error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
```

---

The only way I am able to get this code to compile through the SiFive toolchain is to change the `li` pseudo instruction to a `mv` pseudo instruction like this:

```
__asm__ volatile(
  "   mv  t0, %[value]   \t\n"
  "   ecall              \t\n"
  : /* no output args */
  : [value]  "r"  ((uint64_t) FOO)
  : "t0"
  );
```

This generates the exact same output that you see for Godbolt's use of "r" above. This approach "works" for me (yielding the same results on Godbolt and my SiFive toolchain).  It annoys me that I have to infer these extra instructions, and that will stomp another register.

---

What is the recommended way to put constants (and addresses) into registers? Is there a special RISCV operand constraint for this?

Why do you suppose that the SiFive toolchain behaves differently than similar vintage versions on Godbolt?

FYI, the code I am working on is part of exception/interrupt handling and must execute as fast as possible.

Comment: Note that Extended asm isn't officially supported by GCC in `__attribute__((naked))` functions.  Only Basic asm (no constraints).  So you might use the preprocessor to embed the number into the string literal (without the ULL suffix if GAS doesn't like that).  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html mentions this).  That isn't the reason for what you're seeing, though; nothing obvious occurs to me.  A compiler targeting RV64 should be able to use an arbitrary constant for an `"i"` constraint.

Comment: Also, on Godbolt you can use "compile to binary object" to make sure the asm output is valid; the default is just `gcc -S` which doesn't feed the output text to the assembler, it just shows it to you.  https://godbolt.org/z/9e67qnbE6 shows the expected "Error: illegal operands `li t0,a5`" from your `li` with a register source.  You're already asking the compiler to materialize it the value in a register, so just ask for it in the register you want.  (e.g. with `register uint64_t tmp asm("t0") = FOO;`, to make `"r"(tmp)` pick `t0`.)

Comment: Is `int` of same size in all compilers?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: I'd be surprised if there are any RISC-V ABIs with an `int` that isn't 32-bit.  If you're wondering if any of them might actually be compiling for RV32, so the register width is too small for `38780996765031` or an `38780996765031ULL` can't match an `"i"` constraint (which means immediate, not int), that's a separate question, but `sizeof(long)` is typically register width on GNU systems which are at least 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. Indeed, when I moved my issue to GodBolt prior to posting here, I *added* the "naked" attribute, and I didn't check "compile to binary object".

Comment: In my real-world I don't think I'll ever have a huge constant like that.  I could be convinced something is wrong in my toolchain, but I don't have time to figure it out. I'm going with the "r" constraints and the "mv" pseudo instructions that I mentioned...  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need an `mv`, just ask the compiler to materialize the constant in the register you want, using `register int myval asm("x1") = 1234;` or whatever.  That forces an `"r"` or `"+r"` constraint to pick `x1`, so that register has that value at the start of your asm template.  (Use `"+r"` if you want to overwrite that register.)  Or if you don't need to nail down a specific hard register, let the compiler pick a register for you by just using `[name] "r"(var)` without a register-asm local variable, and you can use `%[name]` in the asm template to expand to `x10` or whatever reg GCC picked